# Web service soap authentication with javax problem

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I have a web service called **FCSAPreval** at this address **https://fcsa-test-preval-ws.gaa.qc.ca/fcsa-preval.svc?wsdl**.

I was able to get all the classes from the WSDL of the web service using **wsimport** command.
[image]

I have a problem while trying to get access to this service with soap, my code is :

```
       URL url = new URL("https://fcsa-test-preval-ws.gaa.qc.ca/fcsa-preval.svc?wsdl");
       QName qname = new QName("https://fcsa-test-preval-ws.gaa.qc.ca/", "FCSAPreval");

       Service service = Service.create(url, qname);
       FCSAPreval hello = service.getPort(FCSAPreval.class);
```

It keep throwing this error :

```
xception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: {https://fcsa-test-preval-ws.gaa.qc.ca/}fcsa-preval.svc is not a valid service. The valid services are : {http://tempuri.org/}FCSAPreval
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:310)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:215)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:196)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:192)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:104)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:77)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.create(Service.java:707)
at test.test.main(test.java:39)
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the correct namespace as defined in your wsdl:

```
<wsdl:definitions .... name="FCSAPreval" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
```

As:

```
QName qname = new QName("http://tempuri.org/", "FCSAPreval");
```

Comment: I think so, it looks like nameSpace problem